# What is Pythonic way to assign empty list to variables?

Tags: python

I want to assign empty list to multiple variables. I have tried these:

```
# method 1
a = b = []

# method 2
c, d = [], []


print('\nBefore')
print(f'a: id={id(a)} value={a}')
print(f'b: id={id(b)} value={b}')
print(f'c: id={id(c)} value={c}')
print(f'd: id={id(d)} value={d}')

b = [1,2,5]
c = [6,4,2]

print('\nAfter')
print(f'a: id={id(a)} value={a}')
print(f'b: id={id(b)} value={b}')
print(f'c: id={id(c)} value={c}')
print(f'd: id={id(d)} value={d}')
```

The difference, that I can see, is that both a and b point to the same location at initialize but changes after assignments. What is the Pythonic way to assign empty list to multiple variables?

> **Edit:** Question is not about how to assign multiple variables but what is the Pythonic way(better way) of assigning multiple variables.

Comment: `a,b = list(), list()` is you need the lists to be separate objects (working around interning)

Comment: I read that [] is better that list()! As list() evokes a function

Comment: My fav is `a, b = [[] for _ in range(2)]`

Comment: I am not sure it is duplicated as the question is which way is better and not how to assign variables

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Depends on how you define "better". If you want all the variables to point to the same list object, use your first method. If you want them all to be separate list objects, use the second (or any of the others in the dupe target).

Comment: My fav is `c, d = [[]] * 2`, but I'm ok to have the change reflected in the other if one changes.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Regarding your edit, what makes you think that the methods in the dupe target aren't "Pythonic"?

Comment: The two assignments to `b` are unrelated.  Same for `c`.  There's no point to assigning `b=[]` unless you intend to `append` to `b` or actually need an empty array.  We can't set the `type` of a variable with any sort of initial assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
a = b = c = d = []
```

Rather pythonic in my opinion, although this will be the same reference o a singular list object (`a.append("foo")` also mutates `b`, `c`, and `d`).

To initialize completely separate list objects, as pointed out in the comments:

```
a, b, c, d = ([] for _ in range(4))
```

or

```
a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []     # or list(), list(), list(), list()
```

It's not hugely pretty, I agree. But do you really need four separate list variables? Here's what I think you should do:

```
lists = ([] for _ in range(4))
```

Then you can access the different lists using `lists[0]` to `lists[3]`.

Comment: `a = b = []` means that any inplace change to `a` will appear in `b` as well.  `b` is just another 'name' for the 'a' object.

Comment: @hpaulj I think that was made pretty clear by the sentences immediately following it.